# MongoDB C# Drivers in VB.NET Sample

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb, driver

Anyone as sample code for find, projection, filters.. in VB.NET using the LATEST C# Driver from MongoDB (2.2).

I'm struggling to combine Filters and Projection in a find query. There is pretty much nothing on the NET using VB and the latest Driver

```
        Dim f As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Text(search) And Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq("Roles.RoleId", 10)
        Dim p As ProjectionDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("LastName")
        Dim query = Collection.FindSync(f).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net code is little bit different from C# in this context 
so filter can be done as

Dim f As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = new BsonDocument("Roles.RoleId", variabletype.roleid)
         Dim sort =  Builders( Of BsonDocument).Sort.Descending("datetime")

```
        Dim query As Object = collection.Find(f).Sort(sort).ToList


 Dim f As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Text(search) And Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq("Roles.RoleId", 10)
    Dim p As ProjectionDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("LastName")
    Dim query = Collection.FindSync(f).ToList
```